# How scrape comment by soup

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like scrape comments from this site https://www.ceneo.pl/sklepy/morele.net-s379
But after scrpaed i got empty file. What i did wrong ?
This is my code

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://www.ceneo.pl/sklepy/morele.net-s379")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser",
).find_all("div", class_="js_shop-reviews js_shop reviews-offer")

morele = [[ i.getText(strip=True) for i in div.find("div") if i.getText()] for div in soup]


csv_table = pd.DataFrame(morele)
csv_table = csv_table.reset_index(drop=True)
csv_table.insert(0,'No.',csv_table.index)

#print(csv_table)

#Export to Csv file
csv_table.to_csv(r'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/morele.csv',";",encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this
I found the comment was under class `user-post__text` so changed it.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://www.ceneo.pl/sklepy/morele.net-s379")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser",
).find_all("div", {"class":"user-post__text"}) #changes made here 
# print(soup)
morele = [div.getText(strip=True) for div in soup] #and here as well

print(morele)
csv_table = pd.DataFrame(morele)
csv_table = csv_table.reset_index(drop=True)
csv_table.insert(0,'No.',csv_table.index)

#print(csv_table)

#Export to Csv file
csv_table.to_csv(r'morele.csv',";",encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False, header=True)
```

Does this solves your problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Is it possible to scrappe also note  for example "5/5 Wystawiono dzisia"

Comment: if this solves you problem the please marks this answer right

Comment: i got it . i use class":"user-post__score-count"